# find the area of the shaded region $x=y^2-1, y=1, x=\sqrt y$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

find the area of the shaded region $$x=y^2-1, y=1, x=\sqrt y$$
The shaded region contains the point $(0,1)$

$$y=\sqrt{x+1}, y=x^2, y=1$$

$$\int _{-1}^{1}\left(\sqrt{x+1}-1-x^2\right)dx$$

I'm getting something different than the book
[image]

Comment: What are you getting? What did the book get?

Comment: Have you tried to sketch this region?

Comment: Yeah, I have.  The book gives me a sketch.  I got 3-sqrt(2).  The book got 4/3.

Comment: I messed up... I forgot to get the antiderivative, I just plugged in -1 and 1 to the original equation...

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{y}-(y^2-1) \, dy$$

Comment: Thank you!  Using y seems easier, didn't realize I could do it like that.  It seems like the y=1 just disappears, could you explain what happens with that for me?

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand.  The integral is from 0 to 1, the 1 comes from y=1?

Comment: Also, you know how when you find area between curves, you take $$\int_a^b \text{top function} - \text{bottom function} \, dx$$ to find area, with $a,b$ the vertical limits of integration? Well, with $dy$ you can do this just as well: $$\int_c^d \text{right function} - \text{left function} \, dy$$ with $c,d$ the horizontal limits of integration.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice there's a fourth boundary in the picture you forgot to mention: $y=0$.  If you really wanted to integrate over $x$, you would need to split up the integral.  Left of the $y$-axis, the top curve is $y=\sqrt{x+1}$ and the bottom curve is $y=0$.  Right of the $y$-axis, you have $y=1$ on top and $y=x^2$ on the bottom.  Therefore, your integral would be

$$\int_{-1}^0\sqrt{x+1}dx+\int_0^1(1-x^2)dx$$

Looks like the first integral is $\frac23$ while the second is $1-\frac13$.  Add those and you have your book's answer.  The problem looks like it was made to be integrated over $y$ though, especially since you have $x$ given as a function of $y$.